# What is the difference between using plain {} and typing.Dict in function parameters types?

Tags: python, function, parameters, type-hinting, python-typing

Considering the following function:

```
import typing

def foo(dict_1: {}, dict_2: typing.Dict):
    pass
```

I was wondering if there is any difference between using {} for dict_1 and typing.Dict for dict_2 as a parameters type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think nobody should use the first notation, although technically there's nothing wrong with it.

One important distinction is that `typing.Dict` supports the `[]` notation that allows for type hinting keys and values too.

Also note that `typing.Dict` is deprecated since *3.9+* (see *PEP585*), since `builtins.dict` now supports the `[]` notation as well.

Another side note but slightly *OT*, one shouldn't even use `dict`s when type hinting function parameters since they're too concrete. Abstracts like `Mapping` are more suitable, while `dict`s are clearly ok for return values.

Comment: Thank you for that comprehensive answer. I also find using only {} too concrete and better to use something from 'typing' or 'builtins'.  I also think I need to delve into the subject of PEP585.